# How to override this subscript for Swift Dictionary?

Tags: swift, subscript

I'm writing a subscript for `Dictionary<String, Any>`, where i do not want to add nil values to the dictionary. I'm doing an if let to unwrap the value before I set it, then not adding it if its `nil`

```
extension Dictionary where Key == String, Value == Any {
    subscript(key: Key) -> Value? {
        get {
            return self[key]
        }
        set(newValue) { 
            if let newValue = newValue {
               self[key] = newValue
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

Problem here is that the `get { self[key] }` will be recursive. How can i do this type of subscript for a Swift `Dictionary`? I can't use the "regular" get set, so is this not possible?

Comment: The standard Dictionary behavior is not to *add nil values*, instead the key is removed if the value is `nil`.

Comment: "i do not want to add nil values to the dictionary" It's very hard to _accidentally_ add `nil` to a `[String: Any]` (`someDict[someKey] = nil` will remove the value, rather than adding `nil` to it), so you are trying to prevent people from _intentionally_ adding `nil` to `[String: Any]`? Why? That should be a perfectly valid value.

Comment: What I am saying is, this sounds like an XY problem. Anyway, you are not supposed to use extensions to _override_ things. They are supposed to _extend_.